если бы ещё так
This is from РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ (1924):

И если бы ещё такъ, если бы къ мѣсту тутъ былъ Самсонъ, хотя бы и
ослѣплённый!

Shouldn't this be если бы ещё так БЫЛО? Or does the был later in the sentence apply to both of the clauses with если?
I think если бы ещё так means "if only it were so"?

You're right, если бы ещё так means "if only it were so".
Если бы так is a set phrase, meaning if (it were) so:


Говорят, что идеология мешает ему стать иным.  Если бы так!  Это он-то сверяет каждый свой шаг по Марксу? [Владимир Войнович. Иванькиада, или рассказ о вселении писателя Войновича в новую квартиру (1976)]
Если бы так, я бы в этой дыре не сидел! — в сердцах произнес Шалико. [Михаил Гиголашвили. Чертово колесо (2007)]
Мария Александровна грустно улыбнулась:    — Если бы так!  Люди думают лишь о себе [Николай Дежнев. Год бродячей собаки (2002)]


Ещё, in this context, is an intensifier, used with subjunctive and conditional constructs to amplify the irreality of the hypothetical part:


И ведь если бы еще в самом деле сила неодолимая, натура высшего разряда тяготела над этими несчастными! [Н. А. Добролюбов. Темное царство (1859)]
Если бы еще переход воды из твердого состояния в капельножидкое сопровождался не уменьшением, а увеличением объема, то можно было бы объяснить неплавкость льда внутри его массы недостатком места, или — что все равно — тем сопротивлением, которое каждая его частичка встретила бы со стороны окружающей однородной с нею массы; но этой-то причины именно и не существует [так как при таянии льда происходит уменьшение объема]. [А. М. Бутлеров. Теоретические и экспериментальные работы по химии (1851-1886)]
И если бы ты еще доподлинно эту бочку не поставил, а то ведь только накричал, нашумел!.. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Завещание моим детям (1866)]


It means "if only it were A, then, of course, B", implying that in fact it wasn't A, and B can't be justified by A happening.

I was focusing on the lack of было, but this is all good as a reply. Thanks.
